# error when executing guard in project folder

Tags: rubygems, guard

I am working with a project using guard. When I try to type 'guard' in the project it gives me the following error. The folder has a valid Guardfile  -

```
/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:50:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:50:in `setup'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:183:in `start'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying running:

```
bundle exec guard
```

and this is [another thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163811) that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring because the dir had been deleted.